# What is the noun for "marks you make on your book"?

Tags: nouns

I want a noun for "notes you take and marks you make on your book while reading"?
Should it be "markups" ? or something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term [markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) tends to be reserved for what is / was done by

> 'skilled typographers known as "markup men" or "copy markers"  who
>   marked up text to indicate what typeface, style, and size should be
>   applied to each part, and then passed the manuscript to others for
>   typesetting by hand ... editors, proofreaders, publishers, and graphic
>   designers, and indeed by document authors.'

And workers in digital media.

[Annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annotation) is the more general term:

> 'An annotation is metadata (e.g. a comment, explanation,
>   presentational markup) attached to text, image, or other data. Often
>   annotations refer to a specific part of the original data. . .
>   Students often highlight or underline passages in books in order to
>   refer back to key phrases easily, or add marginalia to aid studying.
>   One educational technique when analyzing prose literature is to have
>   students or teachers circle the names of characters and put
>   rectangular boxes around phrases identifying the setting of a given
>   scene.'

AHD licenses the concrete as well as the abstract ('making of') sense:

> 1. The act or process of furnishing critical commentary or explanatory notes.
> 2. A critical or explanatory note. . .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a better alternative to *note* and *gloss* (and perhaps *glossary*), a formal word is ***exegesis*** meaning explanation or exposition of a sentence or a word. 
Wikipedia further explains the application of this word as follows:

> in contemporary usage it has broadened to mean a critical explanation of any text, and the term "biblical exegesis" is used for greater specificity.

*Annotation* of course is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: ‘Exegesis’ is in my experience very rarely used in this sense: when used, it is nearly always in the sense “critical explanation or interpretation of a text, especially scripture” (particularly in the genre of Biblical exegesis). As such, I think you would almost certainly be misunderstood if you used it for notes you make in your text book.

Comment: I'm with Janus.

Answer (score 0):

Markup is also used in computing as a term meaning to annotate text to describe it's purpose; you can say make this text a header, and that text a paragraph. It's how your computer rendered this webpage properly.

I think *marginalia* best describes what your producing when you add notes and other marks to a document.

Answer (score -1):

... marks you make on your 'text' book?        We normally just called them 'page marks' or 'margin marks' or highlighted.